# Ng-bootstrap 'ngbPopover' not when the parent container has a 'transform' css property

Tags: css, angular, ng-bootstrap

I was trying yo use Ng-bootstrap 'ngbPopover' feature but it wasn't working. The popover would not appear after clicking the button. After hours of debugging I finally found the cause of my problems.

It was the css transform property in the parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research I have come to the understanding that the transform property does indeed affect the css position property of child elements (see: [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)), and it seems that for the case of the ng-bootsrap pop-over it makes the component not work as it should.

To overcome this I added `position: relative` in the css of pop-over button container and it worked.